# What I/O function should I use to write to a .bmp file?

Tags: c++, bitmap, fstream

The example code I've seen for this seems to use standard C file output functions, but I'd like to make it in C++.

I tried using fsteam functions to do it, but no data is written to the .bmp file at all.

So far, I have tried the standard <<, put, and write, and none of these work. If I open it up with a hex editor, the file is still empty.

It's odd, since the input functions work fine.

Here's a piece of the code I used to test to see if it was working:

```
output.open("WHITE.bmp");
output.put('B'); // this doesn't seem to work, the file is empty when I open it in a hex editor. 
output.put('M');
```

And the rest of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned char  byte;
typedef unsigned short dbyte;

struct BMPINFO
{
    int width;
    int height;
};

int main()
{
    ifstream sourcefile;
    ofstream output;

    int threshold = 150;



    sourcefile.open("RED.bmp");


    if(sourcefile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Could not open RED.bmp" << endl;
        return 1;
    }


    if(sourcefile.get() == 'B')
    {
        if(sourcefile.get() == 'M')
        {
            cout << "RED.bmp is a valid .bmp file" << endl;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "RED.bmp is not a valid .bmp file" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    BMPINFO image;

    // seeks to bitmap width, this file is little end in.

    sourcefile.seekg (0x12, ios::beg);

    unsigned int i = (unsigned)sourcefile.get(); 
    i += (unsigned)sourcefile.get() << 8;


    image.width = i;

    cout << "The width of the image is: " << image.width << endl;

    sourcefile.seekg (0x16, ios::beg);

    i = sourcefile.get(); 
    i += (unsigned)sourcefile.get() << 8;

    image.height = i;


    cout << "The height of the image is: " << image.height << endl;

    int loc_pixels;

    sourcefile.seekg (0x0A, ios::beg);

    loc_pixels = sourcefile.get();

    cout << "Location of pixel array is: " << loc_pixels << endl;


    output.open("WHITE.bmp");

    output.put('B'); // this doesn't seem to work, the file is empty when I open it in a hex editor. 
    output.put('M');

    if(output.bad())
    {
        cout << "the attempt to output didn't work" << endl;
        return 1;
    }


    sourcefile.seekg(loc_pixels, ios::beg);

    char data[30000];

    output.close();


    return 0;
}
```

Is there a special function I should be using to output to this .bmp file?

EDIT - added more code, though most of it doesn't have to do with file output

Comment: Need to see more code --- a .bmp file is no differfent than any other file from the perspective of i/o functions.

Comment: Psychic debugging: put `output.close();` when you're done with the file. I don't think its being flushed.

Comment: I forgot that at first, but I fixed that a while ago. It didn't have any visible effect on the file

Comment: Could you remove all the unnecessary blank lines, commented out code etc.  in your code, so that it is more readable?

Comment: When I compile your code (with the necessary `#includes` and `using`s), it works fine on my Ubuntu 10.04.2 system with g++. Is it possible you are pointing your hex editor at the wrong file, or running this in a different directory?

Comment: What are the image height and width in RED.bmp? I wonder if you are overflowing your `data` array.

Comment: @Rob - nope... I'm definitely looking at the right file, if I delete WHITE.BMP it re-appears, opening it shows an empty file. Are you sure WHITE.BMP is non-empty when you run it? I've been compiling it in MVC++ 2005 express edition, on Windows XP.

Comment: Yes, my WHITE.bmp is non-empty. Specifically, it has a file length of `2`, and contains `'B'` and `'M'`.

Comment: @Rob - that was it, it was too big. I decided to make the image 750x410 to test something, and I forgot to change it back. When I changed it to 64x64, it worked fine. I didn't even think to check if my new dimensions made the span of data greater than 30,000 until you mentioned it, thank you!

Comment: You are sure you are flush() and close()ing?

Comment: @John -- he doesn't need to, if `main` returns. When `output` is destroyed, it will `flush` and `close` itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a buffer overflow bug in this code:

```
char data[30000];    // Prepare file for usage -- just copy one thing from the file to the other
sourcefile.read(data, image.height * image.width );
```

You are reading in `image.height*image.width` bytes, and trying to fit them into `30000` bytes. You should structure your code so that those two numbers are related.

Try this:

```
std::vector<char> data(image.height * image.width);
sourcefile.read(&data[0], data.size());
```

Comment: Don't forget that BMP file widths are padded to make them a multiple of 4 bytes. You may need to add that padding to the width before you multiply it.

Comment: @Mark - Does the image width at address     0x12 include padding?

Comment: @jwaffe, no the image width does not include the padding. Most of the time you'll never notice since most widths will be a multiple of 4 already. One more thing, the width is given in pixels not bytes - you'll have to multiply by the bytes per pixel, then add the padding to get the multiple of 4.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great description [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/).

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("WHITE.bmp", ios::out | ios::binary); // opening in binary mode
myfile << 'B';
myfile << 'M';
myfile.close();
```

Comment: Thanks, but Rob figured it out, my input image was too large for my data array.